# Was any belief about the nature of the soul before birth widespread enough to influence common people's lives?

Tags: middle-ages, religion, christianity, philosophy, history-of-ideas

Medieval (European Christian 5-15th century) theologians used to argue between a few ideas about the origin of the soul ([creationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creationism_(soul)), [traducianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traducianism) & [pre-existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-existence)). However, was any belief about the origin of the soul widespread enough in this spacetime, that it would also affect the [common people's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commoner) lives?

For instance, I imagine the belief in the pre-existence of the soul could imply that the wealth that one is born into could already be a punishment or a reward for one's life before birth.

Comment: Related: [WP: Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul). That site already mentions three different beliefs regarding the origin of souls *for Christianity alone* ([creationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creationism_(soul)), [traducianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traducianism), and [pre-existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-existence). Also, your question *implies* Euro-centrism without actually saying so, which would significantly impact the scope of an answer,..

Comment: @MCW My question asks about widely held medieval Christian, that is, European beliefs between 5-15th century.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for these links, they're a great answer to 1b)

Comment: I support a re-open and would cast a fifth vote.

Comment: Now I'm curious... not strictly related to this question, but I wonder about the trope of changeling children and the notion of ensoulment?

Comment: https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P1B.HTM#$CR The dogmatic references on CCC 366 are: Cf. Pius XII, Humani generis: DS 3896; Paul VI, CPC # 8; Lateran Council V (1513): DS 1440 ==> are all dogmatic definitions post-medieval? I didn't check them, I don't how far they go. But, AFAIK (wiki confirms), creationism was stronger in the East, and it won in practice during early middle ages. Bottom line: you may find non-creationists in the middle ages, preferably early, but they will become rarer. And, IF it was not dogmatic, possibly dissidents were treated as wrong, but not as formal heresy.